# EL define array to output object properties

Tags: spring, jsp, el

In PHP, I commonly would do something like this:

```
foreach(array('street','town','county','postcode') as $e) {
    echo $address[$e] . '<br/>';
}
```

It's concise and easy to work with. Is there any way of doing this in EL? I'm having trouble finding a good way to do it cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like that in standard JSTL/EL, but you could use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) to split a single delimited string to an array:

```
<c:forEach items="${fn:split('street,town,county,postcode', ',')}" var="e">
    ${address[e]}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

*(provided that `${address}` points to a `Map` with the given values as keys or a Javabean with the given properties)*

Or if the `${address}` is indeed a `Map` which contains *only* those keys already, you could also just loop over the `Map` itself:

```
<c:forEach items="${address}" var="entry">
    ${entry.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

*(the map key can in the above example be printed by `${entry.key}`; also note that you need `LinkedHashMap` in order to maintain insertion order)*

Comment: The top solution looks the closest to what i need, i should have made clear though that i need to extract object properties rather than map elements. Is that possible?

Comment: It works for Javabean properties as well. See also the note below the example.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would populate a map or list server side, then output them on your JSP using JSTL for each loop something like below:

```
<c:forEach items="${formBean.myMap}" varStatus="itm">
    <tr>      
      <td>${itm.key.propertyName}</td>
      <td>${itm.value.propertyName}</td> <!--which is same as below ...  -->
      <td>${formBean.myMap[itm.key].propertyName}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```